# How do I extend CustomerPaymentMethod correctly?

Tags: extension-methods, acumatica

I've got something that Runs, but sure doesn't seem correct

Desire:  Add one field as an extension to CustomerPaymentMethod
Code / Table is all below

Issue:
 **Why do I need the PaymentMethodID field, and how do I get it filled in if it is needed?**

Started without this in the DB Table OR Dac.  This loads/works in direct access to AR303010 (Customer Payment Method), but fails on SQL Join from AR303000 (AR Customer)

If I just add to the table, then get "Unable to insert null into field"

If I add into the DAC, then keep getting Null within the DB (only on the extension table)

So this runs, but sure doesn't seem correct.  I'd expect to NOT need the PaymentMethodID on the extension table, since within the DAC from "CustomerPaymentMethod.cs", it's NOT marked with "IsKey=true".  If I do need it, then I'd hope that it gets populated automatically as part of the key

Table:

```
Create Table XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt (
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [PMInstanceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BAccountID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentMethodID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,  /* Problem Child, if not here, fails to load customer screen (AR303000) */
    [CanConsolidate] [bit] NULL,
    [DeletedDatabaseRecord] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyID] ASC,
    [PMInstanceID] ASC
    )
    )
```

DAC:

```
[PXTable(IsOptional = true)]
public class XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AR.CustomerPaymentMethod>
{
    #region CanConsolidate
    public abstract class canConsolidate : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected bool? _CanConsolidate = false;
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payments may be consolidated")]
    public virtual bool? CanConsolidate
    {
        get
        {
            return _CanConsolidate;
        }
        set
        {
            _CanConsolidate = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region PaymentMethodID
    public abstract class paymentMethodID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _PaymentMethodID; // = Base.PaymentMethodID;
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    //[PXDefault(typeof(CustomerPaymentMethod.paymentMethodID), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    //[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID, CustomerPaymentMethod.paymentMethodID>))]
    public virtual String PaymentMethodID
    {
        get
        {
            //return Base.PaymentMethodID;
            return _PaymentMethodID;
        }
        set
        {
            // Base.PaymentMethodID = value;
            _PaymentMethodID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Is "Unable to insert null into field" exactly the error message that is displayed? I find the wording pretty strange and I suspect the error message and traces are different.

Comment: SQL (Yes, pure test box, and yes, know the integrity violations):
Delete XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt 
Delete CustomerPaymentMethod
 
Commented out entire PaymentMethodID field from the extension
both PaymentMethodID  and paymentMethodID removed
 
Open AR303010 (Customer Payment Method) directly
Enter data, try to save
Data, from SalesDemo dataset:
Customer:  ABARTENDE
Payment Method:  VISA
Processor defaults, to AUTDOTNET
Card Number (TEST):  4111111111111111
Exp Date:  12/21
Name: abc
CVV: 123


Save Works fine.
Table has NULL for field PaymentMethodID

Comment: Issue from Customer, join includes reference to PaymentMethodID (too long for comment, picked up from SQL Profiler): CustomerPaymentMethodInfo_CustomerPaymentMethod_XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt -> longname
LEFT JOIN [XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt] [longname] ON ( 
[longname].[CompanyID] = 2) 
AND [longname].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 
AND [CustomerPaymentMethodInfo_CustomerPaymentMethod_CustomerPaymentMethod].[PMInstanceID] = [longname].[PMInstanceID] 
AND [CustomerPaymentMethodInfo_CustomerPaymentMethod_CustomerPaymentMethod].[PaymentMethodID] = [longname].[PaymentMethodID]
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not typical to find `PXMergeAttributes` in cache extension. The closest thing to error message `"Unable to insert null into field"` is the `PXDefault` `PXPersistingCheck` validation.

When you have this attribute on a field, attempting to persist a `null` value for that field will result in an error similar to what you mentionned:

```
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

It looks like you commented it out but I think it's still there because of `PXMergeAttributes`:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
//[PXDefault(typeof(CustomerPaymentMethod.paymentMethodID), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
//[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID, CustomerPaymentMethod.paymentMethodID>))]
```

If the `Base DAC` field has `PXDefault` and you add attribute `PXMergeAttributes` then this has the effect to merge `Base DAC` and `Extension DAC` attributes thereby keeping the `PXDefault` of the `Base DAC` and enforcing that the value of that field is never null by throwing validation errors.

Comment: Tried with no PXMerge, and only the PDBString.  Desire is to have field populated with valid data, if it must be on the extension.  So, with ONLY the PXDBString:  Save works, but null in DB field

Comment: What's the point of customizing this field? With your customization unpublished, are there any issues persisting the customer payment method?

Comment: I think your problem might be related to creating random tables in the database. You created a new table XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt but declared it as an extension. When you extend DAC you should never create new tables with the extension pointing to it. Either you extend the DAC and do not create a table or you create a new table and instead of having the DAC inherit from PXCacheExtension you inherit from PXCache which is used for new tables. Having a mismatch of both confuses the ORM and leads to the error in SQL Join.

Comment: So the proper fix would be to drop the XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt table and remove PaymentMethodID field from the DAC extension. If you created the extension using customization project editor it will automatically generate the database script (db script) to add the CanConsolidate column. If you manually created the DAC extension which seems like it might be the case you will have to create/generate the matching DB script to add the CanConsolidate column to CustomerPaymentMethod table. DB script are stored in the customization project.

Comment: "What's the point of customizing this field?" VAR Isv solution, and from my understanding the base tables shouldn't be altered, to prevent conflicts of using the same name among different VARs.  This would seem to prevent just adding it as a custom field.  Yes, I created the table manually within the DB.  Ref:  "Acumatica-ISV-Solution-Test-Suite-November-2016.pdf", from that "4) Any legacy implementation of table scripts, DACs and BLCs using Acumatica Customization Engine found in extension assemblies and/or project.xml in customization package must be converted to extension classes."

Comment: This approach for extending DAC is wrong, documentation is clear on that point. When adding custom field to an existing table, the custom fields must be located in the existing table not in a new table. Solution is the same, remove the PaymentMethodID duplicate key in your DAC extension, remove the XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt table from DB, remove the create table DB script for XPMCustomerPaymentMethodExt in project editor and add a script that adds the custom field to the original table: 'alter table CustomerPaymentMethod add CanConsolidate bit'